# a Hankel matrix of involution numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, enumerative-combinatorics, hankel-matrices

Let $I_k$ denote the [enumeration of involutions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) among permutations in $\mathfrak{S}_k$. I always enjoy these numbers. Of course, here is yet another cute experimental finding for which I ask validity.

> **Question.** Let $n!!=1!2!\cdots n!$. Is the following true?
>   $$\det\left[I_{i+j}\right]_{i,j=0}^n=n!!$$

Comment: Have you check it for small $n$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Yes, I did indeed and I am thoroughly convinced.

Comment: It is indeed mentioned in one of the comments of http://oeis.org/A000085 that "The Hankel transform of this sequence is A000178 (superfactorials)." But without source. :(

Comment: This article https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL4/LAYMAN/hankel.html mentions that A000085 is one of seven found sequences with the same Hankel transform.

Comment: Is there a Gessel-Lindelof-Viennot proof of this?

Comment: It suffices to prove that $a(n,0)=I_n$ if $a(n,j)$ is defined by $a(n,j)=a(n-1,j-1)+a(n-1,j)+(j+1)a(n-1,j+1)$ with $a(n,-1)=0$ and $a(0,j)=[j=0]$.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson: Lindelof? $\overset{\cdot \cdot}{\smile}$

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Argh, I am terrible with remembering names - thats why i do math and not history.

Comment: This is a consequence of the continued fraction for the ordinary generating function for the numbers $I_k$, or (almost equivalently) that the numbers $I_k$ are moments for suitably normalized Hermite polynomials. See Krattenthaler's two papers on  "Advanced Determinant Calculus": https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9902004 and https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503507.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As in arXiv:0902.1650 it suffices to show that $a(n,0)=I_n$ if $a(n,j)$ satisfies $a(n,j)=a(n-1,j-1)+a(n-1,j)+(j+1)a(n-1,j+1)$ with $a(n,-1)=0$ and $a(0,j)=[j=0]$.
But it is easily verified that $a(n,j)=\binom{n}{j}I_{n-j},$ because then the above recursion reduces to $I_n=I_{n-1}+(n-1)I_{n-2}.$

**Edit**: Another proof along the same lines follows immediately from formula (2.7) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2356.pdf) entitled *Involutions and their progenies*:
$\sum_k\binom{n}{k}I_{n-k} \binom{m}{k}I_{m-k} k!=I_{m+n}.$