# Further aspects of a Hankel matrix of involution numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, symmetric-functions

We have two conjectured generalizations of the question asked at
[a Hankel matrix of involution numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261600/a-hankel-matrix-of-involution-numbers)
by Tewodros Amdeberhan. Let $n!!=1!\,2!\cdots n!$.

**Conjecture 1.** Let $I_k$ denote the number of involutions in the
  symmetric group $\mathfrak{S}_k$. Then the Smith normal form of the
  matrix $[I_{i+j}]_{i,j=0}^n$ has diagonal entries $0!, 1!, \dots,
  n!$,

**Conjecture 2.** Let $J_k=k!\sum_{\lambda\vdash k}s_\lambda$, where
  $s_\lambda$ is a Schur function. Set $J_0=1$. When the symmetric
  function $\det[J_{i+j}]_{i,j=0}^n$ is expanded in terms of power
  sums, then every coefficient is an integer divisible by
  $n!!$. (Tewodros' question is equivalent to the coefficient of
  $p_1^{n(n+1)}$ being equal to $n!!$.)

Is there a nice formula or combinatorial interpretation of the
coefficients in Conjecture 2?

Comment: This is a really cool extension of the discussion on involution. Glad to see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On **Conjecture 1:** As remarked by Johann Cigler in the  linked question (and shown in the references linked there) the matrix $M:=\left[I_{i+j}\right]_{i\ge0\atop j\ge0}$ diagonalises as $M=U^TDU$ with $D:=\operatorname{diag(k!)}$, and $U$ an upper triangular integer coefficients matrix with unit diagonal elements, hence with integer coefficient inverse: so  this is also the SNF of $M$.

For example:

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&1&2&4&10\\  1&2&4&10&
26\\ 2&4&10&26&76\\  4&10&26&76&232
\\  10&26&76&232&764\end {array} \right] =$$$$= \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&&&&\\ 1&1&&&
\\  2&2&1&&\\  4&6&3&1& 
\\  10&16&12&4&1\end {array} \right] \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1& & & & \\   &1& & & 
\\   & &2& & \\   & & &6& 
\\   & & & &24\end {array} \right] \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&1&2&4&10\\   &1&2&6&
16\\   & &1&3&12\\   & & &1&4
\\   & & & &1\end {array} \right] 
$$

Comment: This diagonalisation of $M$  is precisely the same as in my answer to the linked Amdeberhan’s question.

Comment: (Actually I can't see the diagonalisation there, but yes, there is a uniqueness result :) )

Comment: $\sum_k\binom{n}{k}I_{n-k} \binom{m}{k}I_{m-k} k!=I_{m+n} $ is equivalent with the fact that
if $A$ is the matrix with entries $\binom{i}{j}I_{i-j}$   and $D$ is the diagonal matrix with elements $i!$ then $M=ADA^T.$

Comment: The identity Johann Cigler mentioned is equation (2.7) in his link: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2356.pdf

Comment: ok thank you guys