# Equality of determinants: a direct justification request

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, combinatorial-identities

Let $I_k$ denote the [enumeration of involutions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationInvolution.html) among permutations in $\mathfrak{S}_k$. Here is yet another cute finding for which I ask a:

> **Question.** Is there a direct proof (or interpretation or transformation) of the following equality?

$$\det\left[I_{i+j}\right]_{i,j=0}^n
=\det\left[(i+1)^j\right]_{i,j=0}^n.$$

*Remark 1.* I know how to prove them individually, so that's not what we seek here. The RHS is a specialization of Vandermonde.

*Remark 2.* One may consider looking at the two MO questions/answers: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261600/a-hankel-matrix-of-involution-numbers) and also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261707/further-aspects-of-a-hankel-matrix-of-involution-numbers).